# one XCode Project multiple iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment

I tried to create multiple iPhone apps using same XCode project and that worked ok, but when I want to install all of them into my iPhone, iTunes instead of adding the  second app as new, it want to replace the existing one(the first one installed) with the second one.
I used for each application a different target and made a script which copy into Default.png the corresponding image.My app will have different distributions, so I need to figure it out how to deploy the apps in order for iTunes to install each of these as single app and not to consider all my apps as one single application.

Can you guys please help me with this?

Appreciate,
Alex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each target needs its own Info.plist. And each Info.plist must have a different Bundle Identifier set. Easiest way to check is Project -> Edit Active Target, then go to the Properties tab and check the value at "Identifier". It's important that each target has a different identifies, because that is how Xcode/iPhone identifies an app. If you have several targets all using the same Bundel Identifier they will overwrite each other on install.

Answer (score 4):

You need different `Info.plist` files, each specifying a different `Bundle Identifier`, to uniquify them. Otherwise, they each look the same to the device, which will just clobber one for the other.

Right-click on your build target and select Get Info. Click the Build tab, and scroll down to the build setting "Info.plist File" in the "Packaging" section. Set that to a different plist  for each target you have.